# Does the Rig Veda specifically mention any Central Asian places beyond modern Afghanistan?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-india, central-asia

On doing research on the [Rig Veda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigveda), I found that the Bactria and the associated rivers were mentioned. But does the Rig Veda contain specific details of any Central Asian places beyond modern Afghanistan? There seems to be no information on this topic, and any leads would be valued.

Comment: Hmmm. I'd kind of like to know this too, so good question!

Comment: You may find [this](http://voiceofdharma.org/books/rig/ch4.htm) to be interesting.

Comment: @CDR this is really useful! Thanks for sharing. Indeed, no Central Asian places are mentioned as I had suspected.